# Searching for a locale, client-side, embedded javascript -based database

Tags: javascript, database, client-side

I'm searching for a small database library as described in the title, to be used for storing data for a web app that runs in the browser.

(Almost) all the libraries i've found have kinda missed the point:

- **SQL.js** : badly documented, isn't persistent (has to be manually each time)
- **CouchDB**: is actually just a front-end for native browser storage methods such as localStorage, IndexedDB or WebSQL. I'd like instead a database that stores data in a file in the app's own directory instead.
- **NeDB**: same as above, at least for the browser version.
- **TaffyDB**: isn't persistent, has to be manually saved.

I found LokiJS that seems to fit my needs, but has horrible documentation.
Anything i've missed?

Comment: You dont have direct access to your file system from a browser application. This is the reason for saving manually.

Comment: localStorage & JSON ?

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to use localStorage, as i want my app to be portable

Comment: I may suggest alasql.js may help you

Comment: I forgot to include it, but also alasql uses localStorage/IndexedDB under the hood